# Mi código de ordenamiento de datos no funciona

Tags: python, lista, ordenamiento

mi pregunta es la siguiente, estaba haciendo una programa que ordena una lista de números aleatorios del 1 al 10. Todo funciona bien, pero cuando un numero se repite muere mi programa.

Mi código:

```
from random import *

def generar_matriz(cant, inicio, fin):
    matriz = []
    for i in range(cant):
        matriz.append(randint(inicio, fin))
    return matriz

def minimo_pos(lis, n = 0):
    minimo = min(lis[n:])
    mini = lis.index(minimo )
    return mini

matriz = generar_matriz(10, 0, 10)
print(matriz,"\n")

for i in range(len(matriz)):
    pos = minimo_pos(matriz, i)
    matriz[i], matriz[pos] = matriz[pos], matriz[i]
print(matriz)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la función `minimo_pos`, `lis.index(minimo)` que te dará el primer elemento de la lista con el valor mínimo. Si tal como dices, puede haber elementos repetidos, tienes que asegurar que la posición que encuentre no sea del trozo de la lista que ya está ordenada. Debes indicar a `.index` a partir de qué posición empezar a buscar:

```
def minimo_pos(lis, n = 0):
    minimo = min(lis[n:])
    mini = lis.index(minimo, n)
    return mini
```

Comment: Ahhh!! solo era eso, Muchas gracias, me mate pensando mas de 2 horas jeje. Muchas Gracias!!! :).